# Foreign key on two tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hello can you help me with following situation?

### Tables

```
1. News:
- id
- post
- member_nickname (foreign key to member.nickname) (author of the news)
- date

2. Chronicle:
- id
- event_id (foreign key to event.id)
- member_nickname (foreign key to member.nickname) (author of the chronicle)
- route
- content

3. Event:
- id
- calendarevent_id (foreign key to calendarevent)
- timestart
- timeend
- member_nickname (foreign key to member.nickname) (leader of the event)
- text
```

Note: in all three cases member.nickname can be different person)

### Relations

```
- event : chronicle -  1:1
- news : (chronicle or event) - 1:1
```

Question is how to design the second relation with foreign key? Also the name of the key has to be in form **table.column**. I can add some extra tables if necessary.

Comment: You need the supertype/subtype pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two columns to news:

a) chronicleid - the chronicle to which the news item is tied to

b) eventid - the event to which the news item is tied to

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have both chronicleid & eventid in News and both of them can allow null.
Then you can have either a chronicle or an event or none or both.

And if you really want to have either chronicle or event, then you can add a check constraint,  to perform this.